# How to get Eclipse show class hierarchy across multiple PHP projects?

Tags: php, eclipse, hierarchy

I have actually downloaded and tried Eclipse just to be able to browse class/interface hierarchy easily. I noted the "Open Type Hierarchy" feature and it works nice when all the ascendants and descendants of a class are within the same project.

However, the complication is: some classes extend classes from other projects. Say I have the two projects: MySite and MyFramework. A class from MySite project called `MySite_Controller` extends `MyFramework_Web_Controller` which is located in MyFramework project. When the code is run, PHP can see both codebases because autoload is properly configured. However, I don't know how to get Eclipse to know where to look for classes with particular prefixes. As you may have guessed, the two projects  can't be joined because MyFramework is used by other projects as well.

So the question is: how do I get Eclipse to correctly show the "foreign" parent class for `MySite_Controller` in the Type Hierarchy view? Currently the view won't show classes whose files cannot be found within the current project.

P. S. Should the goal be not achievable with Eclipse, I'd like to hear the names of any other PHP IDEs that can do that nice and easy.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by adding `MyFramework` project files to `MySite`'s [PHP Include Paths](http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/help/html/include_paths.htm). Note from Eclipse's help:

> **Note:** Adding libraries or external projects elements to your project's Include Path *will also make elements defined in these resources available as content assist options*.

Most major IDEs support [PHP Include Paths](http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/help/html/include_paths.htm).